# Simple Sandbox Button Tutorial

Tags: paypal, sandbox

It seems it was easy at one time to create a sandbox button but now I'm going round and round on the paypal site and keep ending up the same place.  All I would like to do is create and test a paypal sandbox button.

I've created my test accounts in the sandbox but that's as far as I've got (can I login to paypal using these accounts as so far it appears not)??

Help would be very welcome.

Neal

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a sandbox account, you should be able to login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com with the sandbox's account email address and password. Once logged in, use this shortcut link to get to the 'My Saved Button' page: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-management. (You can also navigate through the account but it varies on the type of sandbox account you have). From there, you can create PayPal button as usual.

P/S: If somehow you cannot login to sandbox.paypal.com, then you can create a new one in PayPal Developer dashboard. Refer to this link for the steps: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/744/kw/sandbox